# UIRefreshControl attributedTitle multiple lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

Is it possible to use multiple lines in the `UIRefreshControl` title? Whenever I add \n to the `NSAttributedString` only the first line will be displayed. I'm trying to set a title and on the next line some more text. So is there a workaround to use two lines of text in the `UIRefreshControl`?

This is the current code where only "Title Here" is displayed:

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

NSString *title = @"Title Here";
NSString *subText = @"Subtext Here";
NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",title,subText]];

[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0f] range:NSMakeRange(0, [title length])];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f] range:NSMakeRange([title length],[subText length])];

[attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [title length])];
[attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor lightGrayColor] range:NSMakeRange([title length], [subText length])];

self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = attString;
```

Answer (score 4):

here is a ***tricky*** method: find the UILabel in the UIRefreshControl and set numberOfLines = 0.

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[[[self.refreshControl subviews] firstObject] subviews] lastObject];
if (titleLabel) {
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    NSString title = @"Pull to Refresh.\nUpdated Time: 09:30"; // \n for new line.
    self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code will work

```
NSString *title = @"Title Here";
NSString *subText = @"Subtext Here";

NSMutableAttributedString *titleAttString =  [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title];
NSMutableAttributedString *subTitleAttString =  [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:subText];

[titleAttString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0f] range:NSMakeRange(0, [title length])];
[subTitleAttString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0f] range:NSMakeRange(0,[subTitle length])];

[titleAttString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [title length])];
[subTitleAttString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor lightGrayColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [subTitle length])];

[titleAttString appendAttributedString:subTitleAttString];

self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = titleAttString;
```

Comment: Does not work, text is displayed next to each other. Does someone has a right answer to provide ?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to change the UILable's property of Refresh Controller to Zero.
The hack is we have to find the label through the subviews and there child as shown below.

Here is a Swift version

```
    if let refreshLabel = refreshControl?.subviews.first?.subviews.last as? UILabel {
            refreshLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    }
```

So here is the full code sample

```
private var marketRefreshController = UIRefreshControl()
private var lastUpdatedDate = Date()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.refreshControl = marketRefreshController
    if let refreshLabel = refreshControl?.subviews.first?.subviews.last as? UILabel {
        refreshLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    }
    marketRefreshController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshMarketData), for: .valueChanged)
    marketRefreshController.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.appSubTitle,
                          NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
    let timeSinceLastUpdate = lastUpdatedDate.timeAgoSinceNow // Date Sting Converter Helper Method
    let displayString = "Fetching Market Data ... \n Last Updated: \(timeSinceLastUpdate)"
    marketRefreshController.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: displayString,
                                                                 attributes: textAttributes)
    tableView.addSubview(marketRefreshController)
}
```

The expected output should be like - 
[image: Refresh Control with multipline text on tableview controller]